# Can't retrieve mp3 duration tag (TLE/TLEN) in PHP

Tags: php, audio, mp3, id3

I am trying to embed relevant information like the name of the artist, track title, album, track number and genre on my mp3 file. I managed to retrieve all of them except the duration. It just gives me a blank result. Is TLE/TLEN tags not supported anymore?  Below is the function I use:

```
<?php

// set error reporting level
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '>=') == 1)
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
else
  error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// gathering all mp3 files in 'mp3' folder into array
$sDir = 'mp3/';
$aFiles = array();
$rDir = opendir($sDir);
if ($rDir) {
    while ($sFile = readdir($rDir)) {
        if ($sFile == '.' or $sFile == '..' or !is_file($sDir . $sFile))
            continue;

        $aPathInfo = pathinfo($sFile);
        $sExt = strtolower($aPathInfo['extension']);
        if ($sExt == 'mp3') {
            $aFiles[] = $sDir . $sFile;
        }
    }
    closedir( $rDir );
}

// new object of our ID3TagsReader class
$oReader = new ID3TagsReader();

// passing through located files ..
$sList = $sList2 = '';
foreach ($aFiles as $sSingleFile) {
    $aTags = $oReader->getTagsInfo($sSingleFile); // obtaining ID3 tags info
    $sList .= '<tr><td>'.$aTags['Title'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Album'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Author'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$aTags['AlbumAuthor'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Track'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Year'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$aTags['Lenght'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Lyric'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Desc'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$aTags['Genre'].'</td></tr>';

    $sList2 .= '<tr><td>'.$aTags['Title'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Encoded'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Copyright'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$aTags['Publisher'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['OriginalArtist'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['URL'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$aTags['Comments'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Composer'].'</td></tr>';
}

// main output
echo strtr(file_get_contents('main_page.html'), array('__list__' => $sList, '__list2__' => $sList2));

// class ID3TagsReader
class ID3TagsReader {

    // variables
    var $aTV23 = array( // array of possible sys tags (for last version of ID3)
        'TIT2',
        'TALB',
        'TPE1',
        'TPE2',
        'TRCK',
        'TYER',
        'TLEN',
        'USLT',
        'TPOS',
        'TCON',
        'TENC',
        'TCOP',
        'TPUB',
        'TOPE',
        'WXXX',
        'COMM',
        'TCOM'
    );
    var $aTV23t = array( // array of titles for sys tags
        'Title',
        'Album',
        'Author',
        'AlbumAuthor',
        'Track',
        'Year',
        'Lenght',
        'Lyric',
        'Desc',
        'Genre',
        'Encoded',
        'Copyright',
        'Publisher',
        'OriginalArtist',
        'URL',
        'Comments',
        'Composer'
    );
    var $aTV22 = array( // array of possible sys tags (for old version of ID3)
        'TT2',
        'TAL',
        'TP1',
        'TRK',
        'TYE',
        'TLE',
        'ULT'
    );
    var $aTV22t = array( // array of titles for sys tags
        'Title',
        'Album',
        'Author',
        'Track',
        'Year',
        'Lenght',
        'Lyric'
    );

    // constructor
    function ID3TagsReader() {}

    // functions
    function getTagsInfo($sFilepath) {
        // read source file
        $iFSize = filesize($sFilepath);
        $vFD = fopen($sFilepath,'r');
        $sSrc = fread($vFD,$iFSize);
        fclose($vFD);

        // obtain base info
        if (substr($sSrc,0,3) == 'ID3') {
            $aInfo['FileName'] = $sFilepath;
            $aInfo['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,3,1))).'.'.hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,4,1)));
        }

        // passing through possible tags of idv2 (v3 and v4)
        if ($aInfo['Version'] == '4.0' || $aInfo['Version'] == '3.0') {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->aTV23); $i++) {
                if (strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV23[$i].chr(0)) != FALSE) {

                    $s = '';
                    $iPos = strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV23[$i].chr(0));
                    $iLen = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,($iPos + 5),3)));

                    $data = substr($sSrc, $iPos, 9 + $iLen);
                    for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a++) {
                        $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                        if ($char >= ' ' && $char <= '~')
                            $s .= $char;
                    }
                    if (substr($s, 0, 4) == $this->aTV23[$i]) {
                        $iSL = 4;
                        if ($this->aTV23[$i] == 'USLT') {
                            $iSL = 7;
                        } elseif ($this->aTV23[$i] == 'TALB') {
                            $iSL = 5;
                        } elseif ($this->aTV23[$i] == 'TENC') {
                            $iSL = 6;
                        }
                        $aInfo[$this->aTV23t[$i]] = substr($s, $iSL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // passing through possible tags of idv2 (v2)
        if($aInfo['Version'] == '2.0') {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->aTV22); $i++) {
                if (strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV22[$i].chr(0)) != FALSE) {

                    $s = '';
                    $iPos = strpos($sSrc, $this->aTV22[$i].chr(0));
                    $iLen = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,($iPos + 3),3)));

                    $data = substr($sSrc, $iPos, 6 + $iLen);
                    for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a++) {
                        $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                        if ($char >= ' ' && $char <= '~')
                            $s .= $char;
                    }

                    if (substr($s, 0, 3) == $this->aTV22[$i]) {
                        $iSL = 3;
                        if ($this->aTV22[$i] == 'ULT') {
                            $iSL = 6;
                        }
                        $aInfo[$this->aTV22t[$i]] = substr($s, $iSL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $aInfo;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: use [getid3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)  for this it allow you to write ID3

Comment: I don't want to write ID3, I just want to read it

Comment: Is your file VBR instead of CBR maybe? VBR can cause problems reading duration...

Answer (score 1):

it is better to use [getid3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) but

you can use this class too

i a little edit this class and 
sorry i don't remember who write this class and original website

```
 class MP3
{
protected $block;
protected $blockpos;
protected $blockmax;
protected $blocksize;
protected $fd;
protected $bitpos;
protected $mp3data;
public function __construct($filename='')
{
    $this->powarr  = array(0=>1,1=>2,2=>4,3=>8,4=>16,5=>32,6=>64,7=>128);
    $this->blockmax= 1024;
    $this->mp3data = array();
    if($filename!=''){
        $this->mp3data['Filesize'] = filesize($filename);
        $this->fd = fopen($filename,'rb');
        $this->prefetchblock();
        $this->readmp3frame();
    }
}
public function __destruct()
{
    @fclose($this->fd);
}
public function fclose()
{
    @fclose($this->fd);
}

//-------------------
public function get_metadata()
{
    return $this->mp3data;
}
protected function readmp3frame()
{
    $iscbrmp3=true;
    if ($this->startswithid3())
        $this->skipid3tag();
    else if ($this->containsvbrxing())
    {
        $this->mp3data['Encoding'] = 'VBR';
        $iscbrmp3=false;
    }
    else if ($this->startswithpk())
    {
        $this->mp3data['Encoding'] = 'Unknown';
        $iscbrmp3=false;
    }

    if ($iscbrmp3)
    {
        $i = 0;
        $max=5000;
        //look in 5000 bytes...
        //the largest framesize is 4609bytes(256kbps@8000Hz  mp3)
        for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)
        {
            //looking for 1111 1111 111 (frame synchronization bits)                
            if ($this->getnextbyte()==0xFF)
                if ($this->getnextbit() && $this->getnextbit() && $this->getnextbit())
                    break;
        }
        if ($i==$max)
            $iscbrmp3=false;
    }

    if ($iscbrmp3)
    {
        $this->mp3data['Encoding'         ] = 'CBR';
        $this->mp3data['MPEG version'     ] = $this->getnextbits(2);
        $this->mp3data['Layer Description'] = $this->getnextbits(2);
        $this->mp3data['Protection Bit'   ] = $this->getnextbits(1);
        $this->mp3data['Bitrate Index'    ] = $this->getnextbits(4);
        $this->mp3data['Sampling Freq Idx'] = $this->getnextbits(2);
        $this->mp3data['Padding Bit'      ] = $this->getnextbits(1);
        $this->mp3data['Private Bit'      ] = $this->getnextbits(1);
        $this->mp3data['Channel Mode'     ] = $this->getnextbits(2);
        $this->mp3data['Mode Extension'   ] = $this->getnextbits(2);
        $this->mp3data['Copyright'        ] = $this->getnextbits(1);
        $this->mp3data['Original Media'   ] = $this->getnextbits(1);
        $this->mp3data['Emphasis'         ] = $this->getnextbits(1);
        $this->mp3data['Bitrate'          ] = MP3::bitratelookup($this->mp3data);
        $this->mp3data['Sampling Rate'    ] = MP3::samplelookup($this->mp3data);
        $this->mp3data['Frame Size'       ] = MP3::getframesize($this->mp3data);
        $this->mp3data['Length'           ] = MP3::getduration($this->mp3data,$this->tell2());
        $this->mp3data['Length mm:ss'     ] = MP3::seconds_to_mmss($this->mp3data['Length']);

        if ($this->mp3data['Bitrate'      ]=='bad'     ||
            $this->mp3data['Bitrate'      ]=='free'    ||
            $this->mp3data['Sampling Rate']=='unknown' ||
            $this->mp3data['Frame Size'   ]=='unknown' ||
            $this->mp3data['Length'     ]=='unknown')
        $this->mp3data = array('Filesize'=>$this->mp3data['Filesize'], 'Encoding'=>'Unknown');
    }
    else
    {
        if(!isset($this->mp3data['Encoding']))
            $this->mp3data['Encoding'] = 'Unknown';
    }
}
protected function tell()
{
    return ftell($this->fd);
}
protected function tell2()
{
    return ftell($this->fd)-$this->blockmax +$this->blockpos-1;
}
protected function startswithid3()
{
    return ($this->block[1]==73 && //I
            $this->block[2]==68 && //D
            $this->block[3]==51);  //3
}
protected function startswithpk()
{
    return ($this->block[1]==80 && //P
            $this->block[2]==75);  //K
}
protected function containsvbrxing()
{
    //echo "<!--".$this->block[37]." ".$this->block[38]."-->";
    //echo "<!--".$this->block[39]." ".$this->block[40]."-->";
    return(
           ($this->block[37]==88  && //X 0x58
            $this->block[38]==105 && //i 0x69
            $this->block[39]==110 && //n 0x6E
            $this->block[40]==103)   //g 0x67
          /*               ||
           ($this->block[21]==88  && //X 0x58
            $this->block[22]==105 && //i 0x69
            $this->block[23]==110 && //n 0x6E
            $this->block[24]==103)   //g 0x67*/
          );  

}
protected function debugbytes()
{
    for($j=0; $j<10; $j++)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<8; $i++)
        {
            if ($i==4) echo " ";
            echo $this->getnextbit();
        }
        echo "<BR>";
    }
}
protected function prefetchblock()
{
    $block = fread($this->fd, $this->blockmax);
    $this->blocksize = strlen($block);
    $this->block = unpack("C*", $block);
    $this->blockpos=0;
}
protected function skipid3tag()
{
    $bits=$this->getnextbits(24);//ID3
    $bits.=$this->getnextbits(24);//v.v flags

    //3 bytes 1 version byte 2 byte flags
    $arr = array();
    $arr['ID3v2 Major version'] = bindec(substr($bits,24,8));
    $arr['ID3v2 Minor version'] = bindec(substr($bits,32,8));
    $arr['ID3v2 flags'        ] = bindec(substr($bits,40,8));
    if (substr($bits,40,1)) $arr['Unsynchronisation']=true;
    if (substr($bits,41,1)) $arr['Extended header']=true;
    if (substr($bits,42,1)) $arr['Experimental indicator']=true;
    if (substr($bits,43,1)) $arr['Footer present']=true;

    $size = "";
    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
    {
        $this->getnextbit();//skip this bit, should be 0
        $size.= $this->getnextbits(7);
    }

    $arr['ID3v2 Tags Size']=bindec($size);//now the size is in bytes;
    if ($arr['ID3v2 Tags Size'] - $this->blockmax>0)
    {
        fseek($this->fd, $arr['ID3v2 Tags Size']+10 );
        $this->prefetchblock();
        if (isset($arr['Footer present']) && $arr['Footer present'])
        {
            for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
                $this->getnextbyte();//10 footer bytes
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$arr['ID3v2 Tags Size']; $i++)
            $this->getnextbyte();
    }
}

protected function getnextbit()
{
    if ($this->bitpos==8)
        return false;

    $b=0;
    $whichbit = 7-$this->bitpos;
    $mult = $this->powarr[$whichbit]; //$mult = pow(2,7-$this->pos);
    $b = $this->block[$this->blockpos+1] & $mult;
    $b = $b >> $whichbit;
    $this->bitpos++;

    if ($this->bitpos==8)
    {
        $this->blockpos++;

        if ($this->blockpos==$this->blockmax) //end of block reached
        {
            $this->prefetchblock();
        }
        else if ($this->blockpos==$this->blocksize)
        {//end of short block reached (shorter than blockmax)
            return;//eof
        }

        $this->bitpos=0;
    }
    return $b;
}
protected function getnextbits($n=1)
{
    $b="";
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
        $b.=$this->getnextbit();
    return $b;
}
protected function getnextbyte()
{
    if ($this->blockpos>=$this->blocksize)
        return;

    $this->bitpos=0;
    $b=$this->block[$this->blockpos+1];
    $this->blockpos++;
    return $b;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static function is_layer1(&$mp3) { return ($mp3['Layer Description']=='11'); }
public static function is_layer2(&$mp3) { return ($mp3['Layer Description']=='10'); }
public static function is_layer3(&$mp3) { return ($mp3['Layer Description']=='01'); }
public static function is_mpeg10(&$mp3)  { return ($mp3['MPEG version']=='11'); }
public static function is_mpeg20(&$mp3)  { return ($mp3['MPEG version']=='10'); }
public static function is_mpeg25(&$mp3)  { return ($mp3['MPEG version']=='00'); }
public static function is_mpeg20or25(&$mp3)  { return ($mp3['MPEG version']{1}=='0'); }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static function bitratelookup(&$mp3)
{
    //bits               V1,L1  V1,L2  V1,L3  V2,L1  V2,L2&L3
    $array = array();
    $array['0000']=array('free','free','free','free','free');
    $array['0001']=array(  '32',  '32',  '32',  '32',   '8');
    $array['0010']=array(  '64',  '48',  '40',  '48',  '16');
    $array['0011']=array(  '96',  '56',  '48',  '56',  '24');
    $array['0100']=array( '128',  '64',  '56',  '64',  '32');
    $array['0101']=array( '160',  '80',  '64',  '80',  '40');
    $array['0110']=array( '192',  '96',  '80',  '96',  '48');
    $array['0111']=array( '224', '112',  '96', '112',  '56');
    $array['1000']=array( '256', '128', '112', '128',  '64');
    $array['1001']=array( '288', '160', '128', '144',  '80');
    $array['1010']=array( '320', '192', '160', '160',  '96');
    $array['1011']=array( '352', '224', '192', '176', '112');
    $array['1100']=array( '384', '256', '224', '192', '128');
    $array['1101']=array( '416', '320', '256', '224', '144');
    $array['1110']=array( '448', '384', '320', '256', '160');
    $array['1111']=array( 'bad', 'bad', 'bad', 'bad', 'bad');

    $whichcolumn=-1;
    if      (MP3::is_mpeg10($mp3) && MP3::is_layer1($mp3) )//V1,L1
        $whichcolumn=0;
    else if (MP3::is_mpeg10($mp3) && MP3::is_layer2($mp3) )//V1,L2
        $whichcolumn=1;
    else if (MP3::is_mpeg10($mp3) && MP3::is_layer3($mp3) )//V1,L3
        $whichcolumn=2;
    else if (MP3::is_mpeg20or25($mp3) && MP3::is_layer1($mp3) )//V2,L1
        $whichcolumn=3;
    else if (MP3::is_mpeg20or25($mp3) && (MP3::is_layer2($mp3) || MP3::is_layer3($mp3)) )
        $whichcolumn=4;//V2,   L2||L3

    if (isset($array[$mp3['Bitrate Index']][$whichcolumn]))
        return $array[$mp3['Bitrate Index']][$whichcolumn];
    else
        return "bad";
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static function samplelookup(&$mp3)
{
    //bits               MPEG1   MPEG2   MPEG2.5
    $array = array();
    $array['00'] =array('44100','22050','11025');
    $array['01'] =array('48000','24000','12000');
    $array['10'] =array('32000','16000','8000');
    $array['11'] =array('res','res','res');

    $whichcolumn=-1;
    if      (MP3::is_mpeg10($mp3))
        $whichcolumn=0;
    else if (MP3::is_mpeg20($mp3))
        $whichcolumn=1;
    else if (MP3::is_mpeg25($mp3))
        $whichcolumn=2;

    if (isset($array[$mp3['Sampling Freq Idx']][$whichcolumn]))
        return $array[$mp3['Sampling Freq Idx']][$whichcolumn];
    else
        return 'unknown';
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static function getframesize(&$mp3)
{
    if ($mp3['Sampling Rate']>0)
    {
        return  ceil((144 * $mp3['Bitrate']*1000)/$mp3['Sampling Rate']) + $mp3['Padding Bit'];
    }
    return 'unknown';
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static function getduration(&$mp3,$startat)
{
    if ($mp3['Bitrate']>0)
    {
        $KBps = ($mp3['Bitrate']*1000)/8;
        $datasize = ($mp3['Filesize'] - ($startat/8));
        $length = $datasize / $KBps;
        return sprintf("%d", $length);
    }
    return "unknown";
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static function seconds_to_mmss($duration)
{
    return sprintf("%d:%02d", ($duration /60), $duration %60 );
 }
}
?>
```

how to use sample

```
 $MP3=new MP3("1.mp3");
 $Mp3Info=$MP3->get_metadata();
 print_r($Mp3Info);
```

with print_r you can see all information like

```
Array( 
  [Filesize] => 8004795 
  [Encoding] => CBR 
  [MPEG version] => 11 
  [Layer Description] => 01 
  [Protection Bit] => 1 
  [Bitrate Index] => 1011 
  [Sampling Freq Idx] => 00
  [Padding Bit] => 0 
  [Private Bit] => 0 
  [Channel Mode] => 00 
  [Mode Extension] => 00 
  [Copyright] => 0 
  [Original Media] => 1 
  [Emphasis] => 0 
  [Bitrate] => 192 
  [Sampling Rate] => 44100 
  [Frame Size] => 627 
  [Length] => 333 
  [Length mm:ss] => 5:33
)
```

but if you want read more information better to use getid3 or develop this class

Comment: Can you tell me a little how to use this class?

Comment: I am not familiar with getid3 since they don't give any instruction how to use it.